Error when adding multiple conditions to an IF statement in C#
I'm currently writing a small program (for a task) that checks if the user is old enough to enter the club and additionally if the user is old enough or too old if there's an underage night. However I get the following compilation errors:
Compilation error (line 19, col 20): ) expected
Compilation error (line 19, col 87): ; expected
Compilation error (line 19, col 87): } expected
Compilation error (line 21, col 4): 'else' cannot start a statement.
Compilation error (line 21, col 4): Syntax error, '(' expected
Compilation error (line 21, col 4): Invalid expression term 'else'
Compilation error (line 21, col 4): ) expected
Compilation error (line 21, col 4): Invalid expression term 'else'
Compilation error (line 21, col 4): ; expected
Compilation error (line 19, col 12): 'bool' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
I'm confused by the syntax errors in particular errors as I've made sure to add ";" and ")" and "{" where required.
Here is the program I'm currently writing:
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int clubAgeMin = 18;
        int clubUAgeMin =(clubAgeMin - 2);
        int clubUAgeMax =17;
        int userAge =20;
        Boolean isUNight =false;
        
        if (userAge >= clubAgeMin && isUNight == false) {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the club!"); 
        }
        else if (userAge < clubAgeMin && isUNight == false) {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry but your under 18, please come back when we have a underage's night"); 
        }
        else if (Boolean isUNight == true && userAge >= clubUAgeMin && userAge < clubUAgeMax) {
        Console.WriteLine("Wlcome to the club's underage night!");
        }
        else if (userAge > clubUAgeMax) {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry buddy but your too old for the underage night");
        }
        else if (userAge < clubUAgeMin) {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry buddy but your too young for the underage night, comeback when you are older");
        }
        
    }
}

I've tried adding parenthesis onto each conditional however this yields another error.
Thanks for responses in advance!

else if (Boolean isUNight == true && ... should be else if (isUNight && ...

Remove Boolean keyword from this condition
else if (Boolean isUNight == true && userAge >= clubUAgeMin && userAge < clubUAgeMax) {
    Console.WriteLine("Wlcome to the club's underage night!");
}

To :
else if (isUNight == true && userAge >= clubUAgeMin && userAge < clubUAgeMax) {
    Console.WriteLine("Wlcome to the club's underage night!");
}



The expression isUNight == true can be further reduced to simply isUNight; the variable isUNight is a Boolean, it will be either true or false all on its own
